# mootools and jquery conflict - noconflict not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a menu to an existing site that uses mootools , my menu needs the jquery library to function . I only have control to add the jquery js files and script and the mootools must be left in the top of the head , and mine must come beneath it. I tried adding `jQuery.noConflict();` right before document ready function and will not resolve. If i remove the mootools js file , menu functions perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www16.myfantasyleague.com/mootools-core-1.3.1-full-compat-yc.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery_1.8.2.js"></script>


    <script id="footerScriptsReady" type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();
             (function($){

             $('#headerTvRotator').innerfade({ animationtype: 'fade', speed: 250, timeout: 10000, type: 'sequence', containerheight: '40px' }); 
                var saag = CBSi.app.SAAG.init({
                'categories':
                    {
                        "tab1":{
                                "scoreboard_url":"#url-here",
                                "ord":0,
                                "menu_subtitle":"<a2>For<BR CLEAR=LEFT>Commish</a>",
                                "default":0,
                                "content_url":"div_forcommissioners",
                                "menu_title":"",
                                "league_abbr":"tabname",
                                "scoreboard_subtitle":"Live<BR CLEAR=LEFT>Scores"
                            },
                        "tab2":{   
                                "scoreboard_url":"#url-here",
                                "ord":2,
                                "menu_subtitle":"<a2>For<BR CLEAR=LEFT>Owners</a>",
                                "default":0,
                                "content_url":"div_forowners",
                                "menu_title":"",
                                "league_abbr":"tabname",
                                "scoreboard_subtitle":"Live<BR CLEAR=LEFT>Scores"
                            },
                        "tab3":{
                                "scoreboard_url":"#url-here",
                                "ord":3,
                                "menu_subtitle":"<a1>REPORTS</a>",
                                "default":0,
                                "content_url":"div_reports",
                                "menu_title":"",
                                "league_abbr":"tabname",
                                "scoreboard_subtitle":"Live<BR CLEAR=LEFT>Scores"
                            }

                    },
                'activeCategory':'tab2'
                });

    })(jQUery);
</script>




<div id="menuContentsArea" style="display:none;">
    <div id="div_myleagues">
        <ul id="myleagues">
            <!--<li class="myleagues"></li>-->  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div_forowners">
        <ul id="forowners">
            <!--<li class="forowners"></li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div id="div_communications">
        <ul id="communications">
            <!--<li class="communications"></li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: you say `noConflcct` not working for you...can you update code to show how you've tried it. Will be easier to help that way

Comment: updated with the placement i had noconflict , if i place the jquery library before the mootools , it works fine as well, but unfortunetly this is on my test site, and on guys server, i do not have control to relocate the jquery before the mootools , i also tried var j$ as mootools if probably using the $ by default and no luck

Comment: the jquery_1.8.2.js file when placed above the mootools everything works fine , but i can't do it that way, so have to find another route...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$.noConflict`. The whole collision comes from both libraries using `$` as an alias.

Try

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
    /* within this wrapper "$" is jQuery again*/
     $('#headerTvRotator').innerfade.....

 })(jQUery);
```

Don't use any jQuery code with "$" outside of that wrapper...otherwise have to use full jQuery word as in:

```
 jQuery('#headerTvRotator').innerfade.....
```

Comment: I have edited my initial post with your change , but i applied on site and still will not work. If i could force the jquery library to load before that mootools all is fine....alas...i'm stuck lol

Comment: also...might be better to move jQuery after the other script files as well..if they use mootools. `noConflict` should be immediately after jQuery.js script tag..even if you have to add a script tag just to call it

Comment: okay tried and no go still ........ since i can not manually place the jquery.js file first in order, anyway to force it to load before the mootools ?  On my test site , as long as that jquery.js is before the mooltools everything works perfect

Comment: @user2200854, Mootools detects the if the dollar sign is already used, so it leaves it free when you load jQuery first. Do you have more jQuery than the one posted here?